# Javascript: Unicode string to hex

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8, hex

I'm trying to convert a unicode string to a hexadecimal representation in javascript.

This is what I have:

```
function convertFromHex(hex) {
    var hex = hex.toString();//force conversion
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
        str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    return str;
}

function convertToHex(str) {
    var hex = '';
    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
        hex += ''+str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
    }
    return hex;
}
```

But if fails on unicode characters, like chinese;

Input: 
漢字

Output: 
ªo"[W

Any ideas? Can this be done in javascript?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Remember that a JavaScript code unit is 16 bits wide. Therefore the hex string form will be 4 digits per code unit.

usage:

```
var str = "\u6f22\u5b57"; // "\u6f22\u5b57" === "漢字"
alert(str.hexEncode().hexDecode());
```

String to hex form:

```
String.prototype.hexEncode = function(){
    var hex, i;

    var result = "";
    for (i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
        hex = this.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
        result += ("000"+hex).slice(-4);
    }

    return result
}
```

Back again:

```
String.prototype.hexDecode = function(){
    var j;
    var hexes = this.match(/.{1,4}/g) || [];
    var back = "";
    for(j = 0; j<hexes.length; j++) {
        back += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hexes[j], 16));
    }

    return back;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just 1 question though (may be a dumb one..) -- how do you get \u6f22\u5b57 from 漢字 in javascript? Closest is with the escape() function but this uses % - I guess a regex of sorts could be used to replace % with / - but the escape() function is also deprecated. EncodeURI and encodeURIComponent both give a different output. Any idea?

Comment: `"\u6f22\u5b57"` is the Unicode escape form of the literal `"漢字"` in the same way that `\n` is the newline character. I tend to use them to avoid ambiguity and avoid character encoding issues. See [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) for details. To generate them yourself change the above `("000"+hex).slice(-4)` to `"\\u" + ("000"+hex).slice(-4)`. The expression `"\u6f22\u5b57" === "漢字"` evaluates to true because after code parsing they are the same.

Comment: Thanks, 1 issue I'm running into, sometimes hex.match(//.{1,4}/g); does not match anything. (error: null is not an object (evaluating hexes.length)) - do you know what could be the cause?

Comment: Must be an empty string. You can switch to using the substr method you used before (using width 4 instead) or use `var hexes = result.match(/.{1,4}/g) || [];`

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! Actually seems to be an issue with ascii. I have a mesage "test", which was converted in hex to "74657374". With your method to convert back, I get "瑥獴" instead of "test". (I do get back the original input with the convertFromHex method in my question) Any ideas?

Comment: If you were using the top algorithm as written "test" encodes to `"0074006500730074"`. There is no ASCII. JavaScript strings are __always__ UTF-16.

Comment: if only using simple ascii, is it not possible to use my original method? Is it in any way possible to detect -> input == ascii only -> use original method, otherwise use your method. I'm guessing that's the easy part, but the decoding may be harder to detect which method was used...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47127/discussion-between-mcdowell-and-wesley)

Comment: I fixed the hexDecode function since it didn't seem to work;

 `var a = "\\x73\\x75\\x62\\x73\\x74\\x72";
 var str = "\\u6f22\\u5b57";
 
 String.prototype.hexDecode = function(){
     var j;
     var hexes = this.split("\\");
     var back = "";
     for(j = 1; j<hexes.length; j++) {
         var xhex = hexes[j];
         var hex = xhex.slice(1);
         back += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex, 16));
     }
 
     return back;
 };
 
 a.hexDecode();
 //"substr"
 str.hexDecode();
 //"漢字"`
 this also works for Hexadecimal escape sequences

Comment: putting the usage of some functions you're going to define later is confusing, I assumed JS had these natively.

Comment: It's important to remember that the result will be in big-endian format.

Answer (score 30):

Here is a tweak of McDowell's algorithm that doesn't pad the result:

```
  function toHex(str) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
      result += str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Why would you not want to pad? now the hex output is ambiguous

Comment: e.g. if you needed to hex encode a string or something similar

Comment: Not sure what I'm looking at, but this is useful for me to get user's private `CouchDB` database! Thanks

Comment: Kudos @redgeoff! this solution works when passing the string into PHP and decoding with `hex2bin()`.

Answer (score 19):

A more up to date solution, for encoding:

```js
// This is the same for all of the below, and
// you probably won't need it except for debugging
// in most cases.
function bytesToHex(bytes) {
  return Array.from(
    bytes,
    byte => byte.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")
  ).join("");
}

// You almost certainly want UTF-8, which is
// now natively supported:
function stringToUTF8Bytes(string) {
  return new TextEncoder().encode(string);
}

// But you might want UTF-16 for some reason.
// .charCodeAt(index) will return the underlying
// UTF-16 code-units (not code-points!), so you
// just need to format them in whichever endian order you want.
function stringToUTF16Bytes(string, littleEndian) {
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(string.length * 2);
  // Using DataView is the only way to get a specific
  // endianness.
  const view = new DataView(bytes.buffer);
  for (let i = 0; i != string.length; i++) {
    view.setUint16(i, string.charCodeAt(i), littleEndian);
  }
  return bytes;
}

// And you might want UTF-32 in even weirder cases.
// Fortunately, iterating a string gives the code
// points, which are identical to the UTF-32 encoding,
// though you still have the endianess issue.
function stringToUTF32Bytes(string, littleEndian) {
  const codepoints = Array.from(string, c => c.codePointAt(0));
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(codepoints.length * 4);
  // Using DataView is the only way to get a specific
  // endianness.
  const view = new DataView(bytes.buffer);
  for (let i = 0; i != codepoints.length; i++) {
    view.setUint32(i, codepoints[i], littleEndian);
  }
  return bytes;
}
```

Examples:

```js
bytesToHex(stringToUTF8Bytes("hello 漢字 "))
// "68656c6c6f20e6bca2e5ad9720f09f918d"
bytesToHex(stringToUTF16Bytes("hello 漢字 ", false))
// "00680065006c006c006f00206f225b570020d83ddc4d"
bytesToHex(stringToUTF16Bytes("hello 漢字 ", true))
// "680065006c006c006f002000226f575b20003dd84ddc"
bytesToHex(stringToUTF32Bytes("hello 漢字 ", false))
// "00000068000000650000006c0000006c0000006f0000002000006f2200005b57000000200001f44d"
bytesToHex(stringToUTF32Bytes("hello 漢字 ", true))
// "68000000650000006c0000006c0000006f00000020000000226f0000575b0000200000004df40100"
```

For decoding, it's generally a lot simpler, you just need:

```js
function hexToBytes(hex) {
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(hex.length / 2);
    for (let i = 0; i !== bytes.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = parseInt(hex.substr(i * 2, 2), 16);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

then use the encoding parameter of `TextDecoder`:

```js
// UTF-8 is default
new TextDecoder().decode(hexToBytes("68656c6c6f20e6bca2e5ad9720f09f918d"));
// but you can also use:
new TextDecoder("UTF-16LE").decode(hexToBytes("680065006c006c006f002000226f575b20003dd84ddc"))
new TextDecoder("UTF-16BE").decode(hexToBytes("00680065006c006c006f00206f225b570020d83ddc4d"));
// "hello 漢字 "
```

Here's the list of allowed encoding names: https://www.w3.org/TR/encoding/#names-and-labels

You might notice UTF-32 is not on that list, which is a pain, so:

```js
function bytesToStringUTF32(bytes, littleEndian) {
  const view = new DataView(bytes.buffer);
  const codepoints = new Uint32Array(view.byteLength / 4);
  for (let i = 0; i !== codepoints.length; i++) {
    codepoints[i] = view.getUint32(i * 4, littleEndian);
  }
  return String.fromCodePoint(...codepoints);
}
```

Then:

```js
bytesToStringUTF32(hexToBytes("00000068000000650000006c0000006c0000006f0000002000006f2200005b57000000200001f44d"), false)
bytesToStringUTF32(hexToBytes("68000000650000006c0000006c0000006f00000020000000226f0000575b0000200000004df40100"), true)
// "hello 漢字 "
```

Comment: Thank you! Two hours of searching and all I needed was this:

function stringToUTF8Bytes(string) {
  return new TextEncoder().encode(string);
}

Answer (score 17):

It depends on what encoding you use. If you want to convert utf-8 encoded hex to string, use this:

```
function fromHex(hex,str){
  try{
    str = decodeURIComponent(hex.replace(/(..)/g,'%$1'))
  }
  catch(e){
    str = hex
    console.log('invalid hex input: ' + hex)
  }
  return str
}
```

For the other direction use this:

```
function toHex(str,hex){
  try{
    hex = unescape(encodeURIComponent(str))
    .split('').map(function(v){
      return v.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
    }).join('')
  }
  catch(e){
    hex = str
    console.log('invalid text input: ' + str)
  }
  return hex
}
```

Comment: for the toHex function, if hex < 10, it needs '0' padding.. if \n or \t appears in the text, it would appear as '9' or 'a'.. but it should be '09' and '0a' respectively.

Comment: you can change it to

return v.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2, '0')

Answer (score 8):

> how do you get `"\u6f22\u5b57"` from `漢字` in JavaScript?

These are [JavaScript Unicode escape sequences e.g. `\u12AB`](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode). To convert them, you could iterate over every code unit in the string, call `.toString(16)` on it, and go from there.

However, it is more efficient to also use [hexadecimal escape sequences e.g. `\xAA`](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#hexadecimal) in the output wherever possible.

Also note that ASCII symbols such as `A`, `b`, and `-` probably don’t need to be escaped.

I’ve written a small JavaScript library that does all this for you, called [***`jsesc`***](http://mths.be/jsesc). It has lots of options to control the output.

Here’s an online demo of the tool in action: http://mothereff.in/js-escapes#1%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97

[image]

---

Your question was tagged as `utf-8`. Reading the rest of your question, UTF-8 encoding/decoding didn’t seem to be what you wanted here, but in case you ever need it: [use `utf8.js`](http://mths.be/utf8js) ([online demo](http://mothereff.in/utf-8)).

Answer (score 8):

Here you go. :D

```
"漢字".split("").reduce((hex,c)=>hex+=c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4,"0"),"")
```

> ```
> "6f225b57"
> ```

for non unicode

```
"hi".split("").reduce((hex,c)=>hex+=c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2,"0"),"")
```

> ```
> "6869"
> ```

ASCII (utf-8) binary HEX string to string

```
"68656c6c6f20776f726c6421".match(/.{1,2}/g).reduce((acc,char)=>acc+String.fromCharCode(parseInt(char, 16)),"")
```

String to ASCII (utf-8) binary HEX string

```
"hello world!".split("").reduce((hex,c)=>hex+=c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2,"0"),"")
```

--- unicode ---

String to UNICODE (utf-16) binary HEX string

```
"hello world!".split("").reduce((hex,c)=>hex+=c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4,"0"),"")
```

UNICODE (utf-16) binary HEX string to string

```
"00680065006c006c006f00200077006f0072006c00640021".match(/.{1,4}/g).reduce((acc,char)=>acc+String.fromCharCode(parseInt(char, 16)),"")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take: these functions convert a UTF8 string to a proper HEX without the extra zeroes padding. A real UTF8 string has characters with 1, 2, 3 and 4 bytes length.

While working on this I found a couple key things that solved my problems:

1. `str.split('')` doesn't handle multi-byte characters like emojis correctly. The proper/modern way to handle this is with `Array.from(str)`
2. `encodeURIComponent()` and `decodeURIComponent()` are great tools to convert between string and hex. They are pretty standard, they handle UTF8 correctly.
3. (Most) ASCII characters (codes 0 - 127) don't get URI encoded, so they need to handled separately. But `c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)` works perfectly for those

```
    function utf8ToHex(str) {
      return Array.from(str).map(c => 
        c.charCodeAt(0) < 128 ? c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) : 
        encodeURIComponent(c).replace(/\%/g,'').toLowerCase()
      ).join('');
    },
    function hexToUtf8: function(hex) {
      return decodeURIComponent('%' + hex.match(/.{1,2}/g).join('%'));
    }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lyquix/k2tjbrvq/

Answer (score 3):

## UTF-8 Supported Convertion

### Decode

```
function utf8ToHex(str) {
  return Array.from(str).map(c => 
    c.charCodeAt(0) < 128 ? c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) : 
    encodeURIComponent(c).replace(/\%/g,'').toLowerCase()
  ).join('');
}
```

### Encode

```
function hexToUtf8(hex) {
  return decodeURIComponent('%' + hex.match(/.{1,2}/g).join('%'));
}
```