# UTF8 char to hex value string

Tags: c++, utf-8, utf8-decode

I need a way to convert chars into hex values as strings.

I've tried a few ways but all of them just ignored UTF8 characters.

For example:

Take character:

> Ş

If its converted correctly, its hex value is `0x15E` but this code just returns me `0x3F` which is just character `?`.

```
wchar_t mychar = 'Ş';
cout << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') 
                  << static_cast<unsigned int>(mychar);
```

I've found a javascript function which exactly what i need but couldn't convert it into c++ [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21648161/3935085)

Thanks

Comment: What's the type of `mychar`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ uhm lets say 'Ş'

Comment: Since when is `Ş` a type??

Comment: How did you get that value into `mychar`? Can you post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: maybe it's user defined, with some modified compiler that accepts non-ascii for names;)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry i though you said value. Its wchar_t

Comment: did you use cin or wcin to input that?

Comment: @ArefiClayton A [MCVE] would be helpful, please edit your question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Even the title is explaining the whole thing but there it is i've edited it.

Comment: @ArefiClayton Shouldn't `std::setw(2)` be `std::setw(4)`?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Have you told it what encoding you are using for the source file?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381614/c-convert-string-to-hexadecimal-and-vice-versa It should help

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i Still get `0x3F` with `std::setw(4)`

Comment: @ArefiClayton I didn't say that this would fix the problem, but you want to display up to four hex digits, no?

Comment: Several things wrong here. wchar_t is not UTF-8 - maybe you meant Unicode and not UTF-8? If you did mean UTF-8, why is wchar_t involved? wchar_t is usually UTF-16 or UTF-32. 'x' is not a wide literal - missing prefix L. Source file encoding matters, so use \u or \x to make it not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning a `char` literal to `wchar_t mychar`. Because char is only one byte long it cannot store the character `Ş`. You have to prefix the literal with `L`, like this:

```
wchar_t mychar = L'Ş';
```

A very good article about Unicode, encodings, etc. is [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky.

Comment: Thank you! Indeec a great article. Got it figured now thanks again.

Comment: Note that `mychar` will be encoded as UTF16 or UTF32, depending on compiler and platform. In UTF8, Unicode codepoint U+015E is `0xC5 0x9E`. There are many ways of converting a `wchar_t` to UTF8, either at compile time or runtime, depending on compiler and libraries used.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you prefix them with L, type wchar_t does not handle international character sets very well.

Try this:

```
char16_t mychar16 {u'Ş'}; // Initialized with UTF-16 code
char32_t mychar32 {U'Ş'}; // Initialized with UTF-32 code

cout << showbase << hex << setw(12) << setfill('0')
     << std::setiosflags(ios::left | ios::hex) 
     << static_cast<unsigned int>(mychar16) << endl;
```

Result:

```
0x15e0000000
```

Character encoding that applies with type **wchar_t** is implementation defined, so it can vary from one compiler to another. 
 Types char16_t and char32_t are better for handling Unicode characters.