# ;How encode string like \x31, etc?

Tags: javascript, encode

i saw a code and that code had all string in a array.. And each array index was like: "\x31\x32\x33", etc..

How i can convert for example "hello" to that encode format?

if is possible, there a online encoder?

Comment: Can you give a example for your string array?

Comment: i need to do so: http://prntscr.com/cnmo88

Comment: Provided an answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39761829/1409180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you console log the string sequence, you get the decoded strings. So it's as simple as

```
console.log('\x31\x32\x33'); // 123
```

For encoding said string, you can extend the [String prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647928/javascript-unicode-string-to-hex):

```
String.prototype.hexEncode = function(){
var hex, i;

var result = "";
 for (i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
    hex = this.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
    result += ("\\x"+hex).slice(-4);
 }
 return result
}
```

Now,

```
var a = 'hello';
a.hexEncode(); //\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f
```

Answer (score 2):

As the @nikjohn said, you can decoded the string by `console.log`.

And the following code I found from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647928/javascript-unicode-string-to-hex). And I made some changes, the output string will be in a `\x48 \x65` form.

It will convert the string in a hex coding, and each character will be separated by a space:

```
String.prototype.hexEncode = function(){
    var hex, i;

    var result = "";
    for (i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
        hex = this.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
        result += ("\\x"+hex).slice(-4) + " ";
    }

    return result;
};

var str = "Hello";
console.log(str.hexEncode());
```

The result of the above code is `\x48 \x65 \x6c \x6c \x6f`。

Answer (score 1):

It is an hex coding encoding.

www.unphp.net

http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/

http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx

are the few sites that can give you encoding and decoding using hex coding.

Comment: It's an *encoding*, not an *encryption*.