# Javascript AND C# Unicode De-/Encode with same results

Tags: javascript, c#, unicode, encoding

I found this informative thread:

**C# solution to de-/encode a unicode string:**

[How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa?page=1&tab=active#tab-top)

**Javascript solution for de-/encode a unicode string:**

[Javascript: Unicode string to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647928/javascript-unicode-string-to-hex)

But the solutions mix the chars.

*Example Javascript (code 1:1 from link above):*

```
var str = "그러하지";
hex = str.hexEncode(); // returns "adf8b7ecd558c9c0"
```

*Example C# (tried 2 solutions, same results):*

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert a string to hex value
/// </summary>
/// <param name="stringValue"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public string HexEncode(string stringValue)
{
  var ba = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(stringValue);
  // SOLUTION 1
  //var c = new char[ba.Length * 2];
  //for (var i = 0; i < ba.Length; i++)
  //{
  //  var b = ba[i] >> 4;
  //  c[i * 2] = (char)(55 + b + (((b - 10) >> 31) & -7));
  //  b = ba[i] & 0xF;
  //  c[i * 2 + 1] = (char)(55 + b + (((b - 10) >> 31) & -7));
  //}
  //return new string(c);
  // SOLUTION 2
  var hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
  foreach (var b in ba)
    hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
  return hex.ToString();
}

/// <summary>
/// Converts a hex value to a string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hexString"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public string HexDecode(string hexString)
{
  if (hexString == null || (hexString.Length & 1) == 1) return "";
  // SOLUTION 1
  //hexString = hexString.ToUpper();
  //var hexStringLength = hexString.Length;
  //var b = new byte[hexStringLength / 2];
  //for (var i = 0; i < hexStringLength; i += 2)
  //{
  //  var topChar = (hexString[i] > 0x40 ? hexString[i] - 0x37 : hexString[i] - 0x30) << 4;
  //  var bottomChar = hexString[i + 1] > 0x40 ? hexString[i + 1] - 0x37 : hexString[i + 1] - 0x30;
  //  b[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(topChar + bottomChar);
  //}
  // SOLUTION 2
  var numberChars = hexString.Length;
  var bytes = new byte[numberChars / 2];
  for (var i = 0; i < numberChars; i += 2)
    bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i, 2), 16);
  return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
}


var hex = tools.HexEncode("그러하지");
var str = tools.HexDecode(hex); // f8adecb758d5c0c9
```

- JS: `adf8 b7ec d558 c9c0`
- C#: `f8ad ecb7 58d5 c0c9`

So the sequence is exchanged.
Both encode and decode works as long I am in the same environment. But I need to encode in JS and decode in C# and vice versa.

I do not know which one is the correct one, if *correct* can be defined here.
And how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both values are correct. It's just that your javascript solution gives you unicode array in Big Endian notation, and C# - in Little Endian ([MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding(v=vs.110).aspx), see Remarks section). 
To make C# byte array same like your javascript, define your encoding like this:

```
UnicodeEncoding bigEndianUnicode = new UnicodeEncoding(true, true);
```

And later use it like this:

```
var ba = bigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(stringValue);
```

**Demo:** [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d34i5z)

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks a lot for your answer. Merry Xmas :)

Comment: Glad to help! Merry Christmas to you to!