# Translate a script text in plain text

Tags: decoding, plaintext

How translate the following seqence:

> '\x73\x75\x70\x70\x6f\x72\x74','\x6c\x69\x6e\x65\x74\x6f\x2e\x63\x6f\x6d'

in plain text please?
It is a mail adress use with `javascript:mailto`,

thanks for any hint,
Joon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Unicode string to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647928/javascript-unicode-string-to-hex)

Comment: Which programming language are you hoping to use to decode?